# How to make socket.io accessible in all routes

Tags: node.js, socket.io, global

I'm building a website that requires real-time communication and am using socket.io for that but am trying to make socket.io global. Have actually tried global.io (though it's not secure, just for testing purpose) but when I use this, I noticed I can't listen for event's using socket.emit maybe because it's a callback

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('connected')
})
```

Comment: Maybe can you use a template engine that allow you to have a layout view, that you extends in each views... (eg: twig.js)

Comment: i dont understand what you are saying, i said i can listen for event from my backend, you are talking about template engine

Comment: Excuse me, I thought that you were talking about all route renderer in front... 
I know you can use Express.js to make your routing, one thing interresting, is the approach of middleware, in its case, you can code a middleware (with you connection), who'll give a access for every route you set....

Comment: pls kindly give an example of a middleware that can do that